# Mac Terminal: Setting Variable using export = $(sed...) acts unexpected

Tags: bash, macos, sed, terminal

I'm trying to save the content of a file into a variable using the export function. However I need to change all line breaks into \n before. I'm trying to use the sed command for this.

When I'm using the sed command on its own, I get the expected outcome. However if I try to directly save the outcome into a variable using export, I get some unexpected outcome. I'm new to this topic and I can find any information why it should act differently.

Example Textfile:

```
#
#
#
#
some text
some more text

test

#
#
#
```

When im using the following command everything runs fine:

```
sed -z ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' /path/to/file
```

However both of the following doesn't work:

```
export TextInOneLine = $(sed -z ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' /path/to/file')
export TextInOneLine = 'sed -z ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' /path/to/file'
```

I get the following Errors:

```
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `#': not a valid identifier
...
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, maybe somebody can help me

Comment: Remove whitespaces around `=`, and add double quotes around `$(...)`

Comment: thanks that worked!, if you create a full answer, I'll mark it as compelte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove whitespaces around `=` and add double quotes around `$(...)`:

```
export TextInOneLine="$(sed -z ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' /path/to/file')"
```